# Why does a domain class behave differently in two different methods of the same GroovyTestCase?

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing

I have a Grails integration test that extends [`GroovyTestCase`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html) with two test methods.  The first method executes successfully, but the second fails with a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`:

> Failure:  testMapBudgetFailure(com.ross.budget.BudgetServiceTests)
>    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.ross.budget.Budget.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), last(), any()
>     at 
>   com.ross.budget.BudgetServiceTests.testMapBudgetFailure(BudgetServiceTests.groovy:45)

Even though the exact same method call `b.save()` is in the first method.  If I comment the first method the second test runs as expected.  **Why are the two test methods behaving differently?**

Full class listing:

```
package com.ross.budget



import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(BudgetService)
class BudgetServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {


    BudgetService budgetService

    void testMapBudgetSuccess() {
        Budget b = new Budget()
        b.month = new Date(2012, 9, 1)
        b.amount = new BigDecimal(10.0)
        b.save()

        Account a = new Account()
        a.name = "Test"
        a.institution = "Test"
        a.description = "Test Account"
        a.save()

        Transaction t = new Transaction()
        t.account = a
        t.postDate = new Date(2012, 9, 5)
        t.amount = 10.0
        t.save()

        boolean result = budgetService.mapTransaction(t)
        assertTrue("Returned failed match.", result)
        assertNotNull("No budget set", t.budget)

    }

    void testMapBudgetFailure() {
        Budget b = new Budget()
        b.month = new Date(112, 5, 1)
        b.amount = new BigDecimal(10.0)
        b.save()

        Account a = new Account()
        a.name = "Test"
        a.institution = "Test"
        a.description = "Test Account"
        a.save()

        Transaction t = new Transaction()
        t.account = a
        t.postDate = new Date(112, 6, 5)
        t.amount = 10.0
        t.save()

        boolean result = budgetService.mapTransaction(t)
        assertFalse("Returned match.", result)
        assertNull("Budget set", t.budget)

    }
}
```

<sub>I know the code is copy paste and not lovely.  It's quick test case for a personal project</sub>

Comment: As far as I understand from the docs, you should either use `@TestFor` or extend from `GroovyTestCase`, not both

Comment: Very strange, can you post the code of the domain classes?

Comment: does it work if you remove the `@TestFor(...)` annotation?

Comment: @denis.solonenko That worked.  Can you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Grails doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html), you should either use `@TestFor` for a unit-test or extend `GroovyTestCase` for an integration test, not both.